# Storyboard Constraints Don't Affect Custom UiView Size

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, constraints, xib

The design of my app involves a lot of views in squares with rounded corners and shadows I thought that it might be easier to achieve this if I just made a `UIView` and add shadows to it in its .swift file so that I wouldn't have to in my view controller. All I did was create an xib file and a swift file and then in the swift file in its `required init` function I used `loadnibnamed` (the name of the xib file) and I added it as a subview. In my storyboard I create a view with set constraints and the class is my custom `UIView` however when I run it, it completely ignores the set constraints. Is there a way I can automatically change the size of the custom `UIView` to match set constraints?

Comment: I don't think there's enough detail here to obtain a useful answer. It's not clear what constraints you are working with, which views they apply to, or what unexpected layout you are encountering.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail the constrains of the view in the storyboard are 0 to viewcontroller - view left and right and 10 to the top layout with a height of 50. With these constraints it should look like a small rectangle however as i tried to explain in my question the view as described exists there as a white rectangle however the shape in the xib file looks exactly as it does in the editor instead of filling the view with the set constraints (sorry im new to ios development so its a bit difficult to explain this).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still confused. It sounds like you have two views here; a container" view defined in your storyboard whose type is the customer UIView subclass you have created and some subview of that container (a "shadow" view?) added to it from a xib file. I think your storyboard has constraints to set the frame of this container view but I'm not sure which of these views is not being positioned as you expected or how it differs from your expectations.

Comment: All I'm trying to accomplish is a reusable card view (like an android cardview) that will automatically resize(keeping in mind that there is are no views inside this card view aka the xib file all it is, is a grey background with a shadow

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish but have a very poor idea of what your attempted solution looks like or what problems you're having. I don't see how I can be of help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution i use view.frame = self.bounds in init and the size automatically adjusts based on the constraints in the storyboard.